# Proof $e^n*n!$ is an asymptote of $(n+1)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, limits

I would like to prove $\lim_{n\to \infty}e^nn!-(n+1)^n=0$.

All I have really done is show $(n+1)^n=\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{n!}{(n+1)^i(i!)(n-i)!}$

Comment: The limit is actually infinity.

Comment: yes, wolframalpha says so, but why?

Comment: Why did you want to prove it is $0$?

Comment: if you change the constant in wolfram alpha you get minus infinity or plus infinity as you move around $e$. If the constant is above e you get infinity and if it is under you get minus infinity

Comment: @Banarama: What constant?  What do you mean by "move around $e$"?

Comment: change $e$ for 2.7 and look for the limit in wolframalpha, you get minus infinity, change to 2.8 and you get positive infinity

Comment: @Bananarama: Thank you. It doesn't answer why you why you wanted to prove the limit is $0$, but it shows why calculating the actual limit might be interesting.

Comment: Your expression for $(n + 1)^n$ does not check out for small values of $n$. I think the Binomial Theorem gives the correct expansion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stirling's formula seems to hold the answer.

$$ \frac{\alpha^n n!}{(n+1)^n} \sim \frac{\alpha^n\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n}{n^n}\sim \left(\frac{\alpha}{e}\right)^n\sqrt{n} $$

Since the exponent grows/shrinks quicker than $\sqrt{n}$ then if $\alpha\geq e$ it will diverge to $+\infty$ and if $\alpha<e$ the ratio will go to $0$...

Comment: I'm sorry, could you explain how to relate that to (n+1)^n?

Comment: @Bananarama I've updated it. Let me know if it's still too hand-wavy.

Answer (score 0):

(This is too long for a comment, but neither is it yet a full answer.)

Consider the Taylor series expansion of $e^x$.

\begin{align*}
e^x &= \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}\\
&= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!}
\end{align*}

It follows

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n! e^n &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n! \sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{n^k}{k!}\\
&= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k = 0}^n (n-k)!\binom{n}{k} n^k.
\end{align*}

On the other hand, the Binomial Theorem gives

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1+n)^n &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}n^k.
\end{align*}

(At this point, I'm not quite sure what to say about that factor of $(n-k)!$ except that it is least significant for the largest values of $k$.)